# How to bundle Python C extension libraries in an iOS app for App Store submission?

Tags: python, ios, mongodb, kivy, pymongo

I'm developing an iOS application using Kivy and Python, which includes the `pymongo` and `bson` libraries. These libraries have some C extensions, which get compiled into `.so` files (`bson/_cbson.cpython-310-darwin.so` and `pymongo/_cmessage.cpython-310-darwin.so`).

When I try to submit my app to the App Store, I receive an error stating:

```
Asset validation failed
Invalid bundle structure. The binary file is not permitted. Your app cannot contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles.
```

I understand that this is due to the App Store not allowing standalone dynamic libraries. However, I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

Here are the options chatgpt offered:

1. **Static linking**: Linking these libraries statically into my main app executable.
2. **Bundling the dynamic libraries**: Including these dynamic libraries in my main app bundle and adjusting the code to refer to the new location.
3. **Switching to pure Python libraries**: Although this may not provide the functionality I need.

Does anyone have experience with this or suggestions on the best way to proceed? Are there other options I should consider?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!